# How to access custom swagger vendor extensions in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

WSO2 Api Manager supports swagger vendor extensions (x- prefix). They are used internally to support throttling. How to access own vendor extensions from code (in Handlers or Mediators)? I couldn't find any vendor extensions registry, or they are not present in MessageContext.

```
{
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "post": {
        "x-auth-type": "Application & Application User",
        "x-throttling-tier": "Unlimited",
        "x-mycustom-extension": "someValue", <-- How to get access to this?
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
```

This is a fragment of swagger 2.0 spec (supported by WSO2 Api Manager). X-auth-type and x-throttling-tier are there already, but there is no way I can use my "x-mycustom-extension".

Comment: Can you specify the usecase here? The swagger template is stored in the registry.

Comment: For each operation I want to pass metadata. This metadata will let me locate fields from the request which need to be let's say validated or encrypted. The swagger is in the registry but it's an extra effort to parse swagger, and to match metadata to the right operation when request come. However looks like it's the only way.

Comment: Yes, you have to access the registry. May be you can use API Manager APIs, through class mediator.